# Element disappears without any command in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a (Hash)map in JavaScript that has an author as a key and a quote as a value. After random shuffeling the authors array to select a key/value pair from the map to assign it to the blockquote/cite elements the cite Elements just disappears. it is practically deleted.

```
// Map set up and setting the key/value pairs
      quotes.set('Johann Wolfgang von Goethe', '"Ironie ist das Körnchen Salz, das das Aufgetischte überhaupt erst genießbar macht."');

      let authors = ['Konfuzius', 'Mario Adorf', 'George Bernard Shaw', 'Oliver Hassenkamp', 'Peter Bamm', 'Benjamin Franklin', 'Johann Wolfgang von Goethe'];

      shuffle(authors)

      let blockquote = document.getElementById('randomQuote')
      let cite = document.getElementById('cited')
      console.log(cite) // OUTPUT: <cite id="cited">
      let author = authors[0]
      blockquote.innerHTML = quotes.get(author)
      cite.innerHTML = author
      setTimeout(findCite(), 2000)
  }

})();

function findCite(){
  let cite = document.getElementById('cited')
  console.log(cite) // OUTPUT: null
}

//shuffle function below
```

i even wrote a findCite function to see if it can find the cite in the dom after assinging the values but it just logs *null*. For a second it still displays "Johann Wolfgang von Goethe" f.e.  but then it disappears.

Comment: Get rid of the `()` after `findCite` when you call `setTimeout()`. You're calling the function instead of passing it.

Comment: Please show us what the relevant portion of the markup looks like. Does `randomQuote` contain `cited`? If so, modifying its `innerHTML` would wipe out `cited`.

Comment: `<blockquote id="randomQuote"><cite id="cited"></cited></blockquote>`- Yes you are right, that caused my problem. Thank you. Is there any way to fix this problem without seperating both Elements in the HTML?